# TypeError: Nodejs.getName is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I try to use instance methods of schema
But fail
It show , not function
can someone explain me

```
const bookSchema =new schema(
  {
  name : String ,
  Author : String
  }
);

const Model = mongoose.model;
const bookModel = Model('book',bookSchema);


bookSchema.methods.getName = function(){
 return ('the name of book is ' + this.name + 'the name of book author is ' + this.Author);
}

const Nodejs =new bookModel({name:'Node.js Book' , Author:'Me '});
const Authorname = Nodejs.getName();
console.log(AuthorName);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 

```
const bookSchema = new schema(
  {
   name : String ,
   Author : String
  }
);

const bookModel = mongoose.model('Book',bookSchema);

let GreenTrees = new bookModel({ name: 'GoodBook', Author: 'Frogs' });

console.log(`the name of book is ${GreenTrees.get(name)} the name of book 
author is ${GreenTrees.get(Author)}`);


let yourBook = new bookModel({name:'Node.js Book' , Author:'Me '});
let Authorname = yourBook.get(Author);
console.log(AuthorName);
```

Comment: hello friend ,what you want to point out , I made const Model for mongoose.model.So dont need to write mongoose.model again . and why cannot get methods function .I want to know is it

Comment: where are you even seeing a methods function?

Comment: Schema.prototype.get()

Parameters

   - key «String» option name

Returns:
   - «Any» the option's value

Comment: bookSchema.methods.getName = function(){
 return ('the name of book is ' + this.name + 'the name of book author is ' + this.Author);
} / is this custom schema methods ?.I call this and use it,but show error

Comment: Look at the code I just edited . I think that should work. Also if you like my answer don't forget to show some love and upvote so other know

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html read the docs a bit more

Comment: thanks bro.I solved .